# TCP Support for AWS Active MQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic

I want to test active MQ behind NLB but with TCP and not SSL.
I don't have rights to setup Route53 and create a SSL Certificate.

As We can see , MQ provides us with multiple endpoints for SSL, STOMP etc.
[image]

since ssl is above tcp in networking layer, does ssl endpoint support TCP as well.

I can not find anything in AWS Documentation , i tried using TCP:443 as protocol on port 61616 and 61617 and 61614 +  HTTPS on 8162 or TCP on all 3 ports for health check for network Load Balancer, but it does not work, no matter what i do , health check does not pass.

any help is much appriciated

Comment: Is the security group of the ActiveMQ server allowing traffic from the load balancer? I would have expected the TCP health check to succeed if the network traffic was allowed.

Comment: @MarkB I allowed TCP on all port from anywhere in security group of MQ but still nothing also added all traffic from NLB security group as well

Answer (score 0):

If the broker is using a transport configuration with `ssl` in the scheme (e.g. `ssl://`, `amqp+ssl://`, `mqtt+ssl://`) then clients **must** use SSL/TLS when they connect to that transport.

To be clear, all transports use TCP. Therefore, TCP is *required* to connect, but it is not always *sufficient* to connect. In the aforementioned cases you need SSL/TLS as well.

Typically the broker *would* support bare TCP connections on port `61616`, but I don't see that transport configured in the screenshot in your question. If such a transport existed it would start with `tcp://`.

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers the question. If the NLB is configured in TCP Passthrough mode, then the connection would still be using SSL, it would just be using the certificate of the ActiveMQ target server, instead of the SSL certificate of the load balancer. None of that explains why the health checks are failing.

Comment: thanks @justin-bertram , so you mean TCP will not work, i thought ActiveMQ will allow TCP as well may be on 61616 with some added configuration.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what the OP is asking. I'm answering from a broker perspective looking specifically at the question "does ssl endpoint support TCP as well."

Comment: Typically the broker _would_ support bare TCP connections on port `61616`, but I don't see that transport configured in the screenshot in your question. If such a transport existed it would start with `tcp://` and be for OpenWire.

Comment: i dont think AWS Active MQ will allow us to configure a new TCP connection

Comment: Whether or not that's the case I think is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about using a TCP tunnel to connect to the Amazon MQ SSL endpoint, then I can confirm that it's working fine with Amazon MQ.
It seems like there might be an issue with your TCP tunnel configuration.
Try checking the SSL connectivity on the port using ['openssl s_client' command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html).
If you're able to establish the SSL connection with openssl, then the problem might be with the SSL host certificate check.
You can resolve this by turning off host validation on the client side using "?verifyHostName=false" in the URL, as explained in the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/ssl-transport-reference).